# Adding new key value to existing dictionary in Python

Tags: python

i have created a dictionary in Python.

```
Employee = dict(EmpName="Peter", Empid="456", Designation="Country Head")
```

now if i want to add to same dictionary something like this.

```
Employee.update(EmpName="Suresh", Empid="585", Designation="Director")
```

Please suggest. i am trying to add another element in same dictionary. but it is not getting added.

Comment: why don't you try it yourself? you should mention what you are trying, what are yoy expecting and what's going wrong

Comment: That will work. But I suspect that it doesn't do what you expect. ;) Hint: dictionary keys must be unique.

Comment: Note this will overwrite the already stored values. Is that desired?

Comment: It seems you want to have a list of dicts.

Comment: @fl9 Or a dict of dicts. Or a database.

Comment: @PM2Ring: so we can't have two name name under same key. any way to achieve this other than list.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with this data. Do you just need to look up employees by their name? Do you also need to look them up by ID, or designation?

Comment: How about something like this: `Employees = {"Peter" : {'Empid':"456", 'Designation':"Country Head"}, "Suresh": {'Empid':"585", 'Designation':"Director"}}`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You should post that as (part of) an answer. It would be better than the existing ones... Or maybe this should be closed as a dupe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you want a table of employees with 3 attribute columns, *name*, *id*, and *designation*. So your data has 2 dimensions, employees vs attributes. You can't do that with a single dictionary.

One way to do what I think you want is this. Start by defining the row structure with attributes.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Employee = namedtuple('Employee','EmpName,Empid,Designation')
```

Now build the employee dimension.

```
>>> employees = []
>>> employees.append(Employee(EmpName="Peter", Empid="456", Designation="Country Head"))
>>> employees.append(Employee(EmpName="Suresh", Empid="585", Designation="Director"))
>>> employees
[Employee(EmpName='Peter', Empid='456', Designation='Country Head'), Employee(EmpName='Suresh', Empid='585', Designation='Director')]
```

Although this is what I think you want, I have to point out that it is not a very useful data structure for further processing. For example, updates are difficult. Suppose Suresh gets promoted to Managing Director. The only way to update this data structure to reflect that is to search through all the employees to find the one you want to update. Or suppose an employee resigns: ditto.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
Employee = dict(EmpName="Peter", Empid="456", Designation="Country Head")
...
Employee = dict(EmpName="Suresh", Empid="585", Designation="Director")
```

And, if you want to have an `update()` method, then create a class `Employee` which contains the `update()` method.

Anyway, as the fields seems to be fixed, I would advise you to use an object `Employee` with the fields `EmpName`, `Empid` and `Designation` in it.

One of the major benefit of using an object (in place of several dictionaries objects), is that you will be able to type (and, then, trust the content of each element) of a collection of `Employee`'s objects. Where, manipulating a collection of dictionaries may just lead you to have missing fields or different labels for each fields.